# Redhat 8 and xorg.conf and x11-xorg-drv-dummy and console monitor and VNC

Tags: rhel, x11, xorg, vnc

For **RHEL 8** not having an nvidia graphics card, I had instructions given to me to do a `yum install xorg-x11-drv-dummy` followed by creating `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "DummyDevice"
Driver "dummy"
Option "ConstantDPI" "true"
Option "IgnoreEDID" "true"
Option "NoDDC" "true"
VideoRam 2048000
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
Identifier "DummyMonitor"
HorizSync 5.0 - 1000.0
VertRefresh 5.0 - 200.0
Modeline "1920x1080" 23.53 1920 1952 2040 2072 1080 1106 1108 1135
Modeline "1600x900" 33.92 1600 1632 1760 1792 900 921 924 946
Modeline "1440x900" 30.66 1440 1472 1584 1616 900 921 924 946
ModeLine "1366x768" 72.00 1366 1414 1446 1494 768 771 777 803
Modeline "1280x800" 24.15 1280 1312 1400 1432 800 819 822 841
Modeline "1024x768" 18.71 1024 1056 1120 1152 768 786 789 807
EndSection
Section "Screen"
Identifier "DummyScreen"
Device "DummyDevice"
Monitor "DummyMonitor"
DefaultDepth 24
SubSection "Display"
Viewport 0 0
Depth 24
Modes "1920x1080" "1600x900" "1440x900" "1366x768" "1280x800" "1024x768"
virtual 1920 1080
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I have a Dell **1920x1200** 24" monitor connected via VGA, and after a `systemctl isolate` in and out of `graphical.target` I don't have a working console.  I suspect it is because I don't have the corresponding `Modeline` specified?  Can someone tell me how to add it, and what the numbers mean?

I would also value adding for the other common larger resolutions such as `3840x2160` and `2560x1440` and `2560x1600`

Comment: The `xorg-x11-drv-dummy` driver does not actually produce any display output at all. It just pretends to be a display, so you'll be able to run applications that expect to always have a display available, even in non-interactive mode (e.g. executing a script). Also, a VGA connector's signal quality is probably not sufficient for resolutions higher than about 1920x1200 anyway, so higher resolutions would either have an unusably non-sharp image, or the display would fail to sync at all because the sync signal required for higher resolutions degrades too much.

Comment: So far, you've only said that the system does **not** have a NVidia GPU - so does it actually have a GPU at all, or is it an industrial server configured for serial console operation? If it does have a GPU, what model? The appropriate line of `lspci -nn` output would be informative.

Comment: a dell r740 server, 2 xeon cpu, only video output is vga on the motherboard

Comment: This is to get a licensed VNC running, and without `xorg-x11-drv-dummy` I receive `xhost: unable to open display ":0"` and I am unable to create a vnc session.  I have confirmed that installing the dummy driver (and with the xorg.conf in place) I can then get a working vnc session, but my console monitor goes kaput.  I haven't scrounged a monitor with a resolution mentioned in `modeline` above to fully verify my *theory*.

Comment: fwiw i tried a 1920x1080 monitor and had black screen with blinking cursor in upper left, so i don't think adding new `modeline` entries will be my solution.  But if anyone can provide those numbers would still be cool

Comment: Googling for "modeline 3840x3260" gave me several hits with lots of modelines, like [this](https://gist.github.com/aacero/7a5f54a44a6e87838b040f3df70c19b1) and [this](https://xpra.org/conf/xorg.conf). With the `cvt` command you can [calculate standard modelines for many resolutions](https://superuser.com/questions/1674634/how-to-calculate-modeline-using-cvt-for-75hz-without-multiples-of-60hz).

Comment: (... typo, should have been "modeline 3840x2160".) The onboard VGA on the Dell R740 motherboard seems to be an embedded version of a classic Matrox G200. So the most appropriate X11 driver would be `xorg-x11-drv-mga` but RedHat apparently obsoleted it after RHEL 6. But you could try a kernel boot parameter `video=1920x1200-32` for a bigger resolution in text-mode console and possibly in X11 too.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem regarding getting a working vnc (DCV) session in Redhat 8.8, which does not have an nvidia gpu installed (so remote graphics won't be accelerated) was to simply `yum install xorg-x11-drv-dummy`.

Apparently that x11-drv-dummy was automatically installed in RHEL 7.9 which is why I never had a problem in the past.  Moving to RHEL 8, that x11-drv-dummy doesn't come along on the *Server-with-GUI* RHEL install automatically.  So I have to do it manually.  And the instructions to do an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` were not needed.  As soon as I removed `xorg.conf` and rebooted then my 1920x1200 console monitor worked and I was also able to create VNC sessions.  This is with *NICE-DCV*.